# Inline sql functions in linq querys without new type

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Looking at this:

```
var t = ctx.Layer
   .Where(c => c.Geometry.Intersects(boundingBox))
  .Select(s => new
  {
      Geometry = SqlSpatialFunctions.Reduce(s.Geometry, degreesPerPixel),
      s.column1,
      s.column2,
      s.column3,
      s.column4,
      s.column5,
      s.column6,
      s.column7,
      s.column8,
      s.column9,
  }).ToArray();
```

its rather anoying that one would have to write all the columns again just to run a function on a column. Is there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Better" in terms of not having to write all the properties:

```
var t = ctx.Layer
.Where(c => c.Geometry.Intersects(boundingBox))
.Select(s => new
{
  Geometry = SqlSpatialFunctions.Reduce(s.Geometry, degreesPerPixel),
  Layer = s
}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres what I did. Very similar to the answer by Eren.

```
public static  class VectorLayerHelperExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<OgrEntity> Reduce(this IQueryable<OgrEntity> query, double threshold)
    {
        return query.Select(s => new
                  {
                      g = SqlSpatialFunctions.Reduce(s.Geometry, threshold),
                      s
                  }).AsEnumerable().Select(t => { t.s.Geometry = t.g; return t.s; });
    }
}
```